# angular2 submit form by pressing enter without submit button

Tags: forms, angular, submit

Is it possible to submit a form that does not have submit button (by pressing enter) 
example :

```
<form [ngFormModel]="xxx" (ngSubmit)="xxxx()">
  <input [(ngModel)]="lxxR"   ngControl="xxxxx"/>
</form
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Maybe you add **`keypress`** or **`keydown`** to the input fields and assign the event to function that will do the submit when enter is clicked.

Your template would look like this

```html
    <form (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)">
      <input type="text" />
    </form
```

And you function inside the your class would look like this

```js
    keyDownFunction(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        alert('you just pressed the enter key');
        // rest of your code
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 275):

You can also add `(keyup.enter)="xxxx()"`

Comment: This works great if you just have a plain old function you'd like to call instead of a submit handler

Comment: This approach were mentioned on Angular docs. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html#!#key-event-filtering-with-key-enter-

Comment: This is the only way it works in my situation, thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Elegance in only the way Angular can achieve. Brilliant.

Comment: New mention in the Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter

Answer (score 98):

**Edit:**

```
  <form (submit)="submit()" >
    <input />
    <button type="submit" style="display:none">hidden submit</button>
  </form>
```

In order to use this method, you need to have a submit button even if it's not displayed "Thanks for [Toolkit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703205/3125880)"

Old Answer:

<strike>Yes, exactly as you wrote it, except the event name is `(submit)` instead of `(ngSubmit)`:</strike>

```
<form [ngFormModel]="xxx" (submit)="xxxx()">
  <input [(ngModel)]="lxxR"   ngControl="xxxxx"/>
</form>
```

Comment: can you please provide a plunker? because it doesn't work

Comment: Use "visibility: hidden;" instead. The "display:none;" worked in chrome, but not in safari.

Comment: This should be used, except that the submit-button should not be hidden but visible because some folks will look for that button and won't bother to press enter.

Answer (score 42):

I prefer `(keydown.enter)="mySubmit()"` because there won't be added a line break if the cursor was somewhere within a `<textarea>` but not at its end.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution - much cleaner

Answer (score 40):

This way is much simple...

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (keyup.enter)="yourMethod(form.value)">

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is easier when I expected. Solved like this: <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="object.LanguageTableData" (blur)="mymethod()" (keyup.enter)="mymethod()" />

Comment: much easier this way rather than sending a function with $event. Thank you!

Comment: much better. no hidden buttons or js. Pure angular way

Comment: Had to do like this: <form #f="ngForm" (keyup.enter)="appendSigBlock(f.value)"> using Angular 9, but works great.

Answer (score 12):

add this inside your input tag

```
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="yourMethod()" />
```

Comment: thank brother. I prefer this option over the selected answer.

Answer (score 11):

```
(keyup.enter)="methodname()"
```

this should work and already mentioned in many answers, however that should be present on form tag and not on button.

Answer (score 10):

Always use keydown.enter instead of keyup.enter to avoid lagging.

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="textValue" (keydown.enter)="sendMessage();false" ></textarea>
```

and function inside component.ts

```
 textValue : string = '';  
 sendMessage() {
    console.log(this.textValue);
    this.textValue = '';
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

Most answers here suggest using something like:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="yourMethod()" (keyup.enter)="yourMethod()">

</form>
```

This approach does not result in the form object being marked as `submitted`. You might not care for this, but if you're using something like [@ngspot/ngx-errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngspot/ngx-errors) (shameless self-promotion) for displaying validation errors, you gonna want to fix that. Here's how:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="yourMethod()" (keyup.enter)="submitBtn.click()">
  <button #submitBtn>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 8):

Just simply add `(keyup.enter)="yourFunction()"`

Answer (score 7):

adding an invisible submit button does the trick

`<input type="submit" style="display: none;">`

Comment: Use "visibility: hidden;" instead. The above worked in chrome, but not in safari.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this can help somebody: for some reason I couldn't track because of lack of time, if you have a form like:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="doSubmit($event)">
  <button (click)="clearForm()">Clear</button>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

when you hit the `Enter` button, the `clearForm` function is called, even though the expected behaviour was to call the `doSubmit` function.
Changing the `Clear` button to a `<a>` tag solved the issue for me. 
I would still like to know if that's expected or not. Seems confusing to me

Comment: inorder to avoid that, you have specify type="button" for Clear button

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include **both** simpler than what I saw here, you can do it just by including your button inside form.

Example with a function sending a message:

```
                <form>
                    <mat-form-field> <!-- In my case I'm using material design -->
                        <input matInput #message maxlength="256" placeholder="Message">
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <button (click)="addMessage(message.value)">Send message
                    </button>
                </form>
```

You can choose between clicking on the button or pressing enter key.

Comment: Had to use this in combo with @Clayton K. N. Passos answer and worked great!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include both - accept on enter and accept on click then do -

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control"   type="text" 
    name="search" placeholder="Enter Search Text"
              [(ngModel)]="filterdata"  
           (keyup.enter)="searchByText(filterdata)">
  <button type="submit"  
          (click)="searchByText(filterdata)" >

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a **small caveat** here, I would say. None of the above would work if you want to submit the form until unless you click anywhere on the form or specifically on the input field.

Well if you want to submit the form just by hitting enter without clicking anywhere, you need to declare it globally in html:

```
<button (window:keypress)="onSomeAction($event)">
```

and in TS file :

```
onSomeAction(event){
if(event.keyCode===13){
  //submit form
}
```

}

**OR**

```
<button (window:keypress.enter)="onSomeAction($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form [ngFormModel]="xxx" (keyup.enter)="xxxx()" (ngSubmit)="xxxx()">
  <input [(ngModel)]="lxxR"   ngControl="xxxxx"/>
</form>
```