# Submitting a form by pressing enter key in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

By pressing Enter key need to submit the form in angular 4
below is my code in form `Action = ""` is not working.
I also tried with `(keydown) = domonething(event)` and `(keydown.enter) = domonething(event)`
with below code

```js
keyDownFunction(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        this.submit();
    }
}
```

Below is my current code

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && openModal(confirmationmodal)" novalidate action="">
    <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label class="col-form-label col-sm-4 col-md-4" for="name">Employee Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
            <span type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="name">{{employeeDetails.EmployeeName}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label class="col-form-label col-sm-4 col-md-4 " for="name">Manager Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8  col-sm-8">
            <span type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext"
                id="manager">{{employeeDetails.ManagerName}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-form-label">Subject</label>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <span type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="manager">{{subject}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success float-right" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577919/angular2-submit-form-by-pressing-enter-without-submit-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 submit form by pressing enter without submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577919/angular2-submit-form-by-pressing-enter-without-submit-button)

Comment: the above comment is also a duplicate of the one above that

Answer (score 8):

give `(keyup.enter)="yourFunction()"` in your submit button

Answer (score 1):

From your form tag I would remove the action attribute and put the following:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && openModal(confirmationmodal)" novalidate (keydown.enter)="onEnterKeyDown($event)">
```

Then simply writing the key down event's function:

```
onEnterKeyDown($event) {
  // here you can open your confirmation modal if the form is valid
}
```

Source: https://alligator.io/angular/binding-keyup-keydown-events/

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
(keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)
```

in typescript

```
  keyDownFunction(event) {
    if ( event.keyCode === 13) {
      // do your function
    }
  }
```

this works for me. I think you've missed $ in front of event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke it with the button then you can do like this-

```
<button type="button" (keyup.enter)="doSomething()" >Click Me!</button>
```

See live here- 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gf6hw

See more about it here- 
https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter