# How to autofocus by default on dialog button from Menu Icon in Angular Material?

Tags: angular-material, modal-dialog, menuitem, enter, autofocus

I have two menu items **Delete** and **Create** under Menu Icon. I am selecting any operation from **Menu Icon** which opens confirmation dialog with two button **Delete** and **Cancel**.

Initially focus stays on **menu icon** after selecting any menu item from menu. I want to shift the **focus on dialog button** by default so that on **Enter-Key** hit , it close the dialog after performing desired operation.
Please check Demo here [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w4bcye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-component%2Fdialog-component.component.html)

Comment: you should recreate the issue you're having in a stackblitz. As far as I can tell, having focus on a material date picker and pressing enter doesn't shift focus to the next element

Comment: Hi bryan60, i have added demo link , could you please check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue as Spinner was preventing focus to move into dialog button whenever i was trying to click on Delete from Menu.
I added `id="deletebutton"` in html as below.

```
<div *ngIf="!loadspinner">  
<mat-dialog-content>
    <p>Are you sure to delete this?</p>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions align="center">
    <button id="deletebutton" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="deleteDocument()">Delete</button>
    <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close tabindex="-1" (click)="close()" style="border-color:#3f51b5;">Cancel</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
  </div>
```

And added **timeout** in ngOnInit method in .ts file as below.

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.service.validate(this.data).subscribe(value => {
        this.loadspinner = false;
          if (value != null) {
             this.warningMsg = value.statusMessage; 
          } else {
            this.warningMsg = "";
          } 
        //For autoFocus in dialog button as Spinner prevents it to set by deafault
          setTimeout(()=>{
            document.getElementById('deletebutton').focus();
          }); 
      });
  }
```